# Append new field to response json

Tags: python

I have this problem

```
line 192, in getstatbygroup
    json_data[i].append(dict({'total': percent}))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

,I found other answers and understood that I have list of dictionaries. But I can't understand what should I do to get the right result.I need to add 'total' field for every man.

```
 json_data=[]
    cursor.execute(...)
    query= cursor.fetchall()
    row_headers=[x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    for result in query:
        json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
    json_datamy = json.dumps(json_data,ensure_ascii = False)
    json_datamy1 = json.loads(json_datamy)
    for i in json_data:
        results = [int(i) for i in json_datamy1[0]['stats']]
        percent = sum(results)/float(len(results))*100
        json_data[i].append(dict({'total': percent}))
    return jsonify(json_data)
```

response:

```
 [
        {
            "here": 0,
            "id_student": 1,
            "last_name": "name",
            "name": "Liya",
            "schedules": "4",
            "stats": "0",
            "surname": "name"
        },
        {
            "here": 0,
            "id_student": 2,
            "last_name": "name",
            "name": "name",
            "schedules": "4",
            "stats": "0",
            "surname": "name"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your problem.

```
for item in json_data:
    results = [int(i) for i in json_datamy1[0]['stats']]
    percent = sum(results)/float(len(results))*100
    item['total'] = percent
return jsonify(json_data)
```